# Gitflow - Best Practice to Deploy Repo subfolder

Tags: git, deployment, repository, subdirectory, git-flow

I have a repo with several folders and a release pipeline for each folder in Azure DevOps (using CI trigger with path filter) so that code in a given folder can be deployed independent of the code maturity in the others folders.

Example:

```
repo-root:
  - folder1
  - folder2
```

Git branching strategy follows Gitflow approach: for example, when code in `folder1` should go into production, new release branch is created (off from develop branch) and pipeline will trigger to deploy `folder1` to QA and Prod environment, subsequently release branch is merged into master (and back into develop in case of any bug fixes to release branch).

I have one concern with this approach: when new release branch is created from develop branch, the release branch will not only contain code from `folder1` to be deployed but also code from `folder2`. The code in `folder2` may potentially be in a non-production ready state. While `folder2` will not go into production (as pipeline only deploys `folder1`), it will enter the master branch when merging release into master. Intuitively master branch should only contain production code, this is why I have some doubts about this approach.

What would be best practice in context of Gitflow to deploy different parts (folders) of a repo individually?

Would be really grateful for some guidance here to avoid moving the wrong direction.

**Update**: This is a monorepo with several projects the team is working on (one project per folder). In principle these projects could be split up into several repos as they are independent, however project admins want to keep the number of repos limited so I would need another solution.

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us why you are keeping two apparently unrelated folders in the same branch. Without further details, I would hardly find any workflow suitable for your project.

Comment: @Marco Luzzara: good point, updated the question as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks, but again: are these projects dependent on each other? I guess not because *code in a given folder can be deployed independent of the code maturity in the others folders*. So, putting the workflow aside, what is keeping you from not moving one project to another branch (or repository) for example?

Comment: @Marco Luzzara, sorry for late feedback, being in CET timezone. Indeed these projects are independent as you mentioned and can be deployed independently. In  principle it would be possible to have them in separate repos but project admins want to keep the number of repos limited so I would need another solution.